# How to increase symbol size of polygons when zoomed out?

Tags: qgis, vector

I have many small polygons. How do I increase size of these polygons when zoomed out in QGIS?  As seen in the image below, the symbol appears to be lost when I zoom out.

**Notes:**
I have created a thematic layer on the polygons.
All layers are vector layers from a database.

[image]

Comment: It would be a solution if the polygons could be converted into symbols/points themselves, which will always stay visible at any zoom level. (The only thing is I don't know how to do that... Should I post that question in a separate post?)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81915)

Answer (score 3):

If you change the polygon style to have a wide outline/border, the polygons will stay visible even when you zoom out a lot. It's not very pretty but maybe it's enough for what you need. If not, please clarify which effect you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted the sumbol to increase in size when zoomed out. I created thematic map but when I zoom out I am not able to see any color but only only black polygon as in figure.

Comment: black is the border color, right?

Comment: Have you tried turning off the border (border style = "no pen")?  By using the new QGIS 2.0 "rule-based rendering", you could also make it more "dynamic", by creating multiple symbols (at various border widths) to be used at defined scales.  ie- when zoomed in close use a thin border, but when zoomed out further, use no border.

Comment: @underdark black is the outerborder. I want the polygon to appear bigger when zoomed out so that it won't disapper when I want to see overview.

Comment: @RyanDalton I made the border with no pen. Now I can see polygon that are blue or green. But at certain zoom level my polygon appears to be point which is not what I want. Is there anyway out?

Comment: @Kitex What exactly do you want to see when you zoom out so far that the polygons go tiny and vanish? I would actually suggest to use a wide border in the same color as the polygon fill when you zoom out. The border will always be visible even if the object goes very tiny.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to RyanDalton's suggestion, try using rule-based symbols, with a simple fill when zoomed in, and a centroid fill when zoomed out.